# Agrupar filas repetidas pero con valores distintos? SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, mysqli, oracle

tengo una consulta que trae los siguientes datos.

```
     NyA           email           telefono
Pepito Perez       x@x.com        111111111
Ana Gomez          a@a.com        222222222
Juan Paez          j@j.com        333333333
Juan Paez          j@j.com        444444444
```

Como pueden ver "Juan Paez" tiene dos numero de telefonos, pero necesito que se guarde en una sola fila de la siguiente forma:

```
NyA                 email          telefono       telefono2
Pepito Perez       x@x.com        111111111
Ana Gomez          a@a.com        222222222
Juan Paez          j@j.com        333333333        444444444
```

Como es posible lograr esto?

Comment: Qué pasa si tiene 3? o 4?

Comment: y tendría que seguir agregando mas columnas

Comment: La pregunta se enfoca en si es un número dinámico de veces que puede aparecer o lo sabes de antemano.

Comment: Es importante saber que motor de base de datos utilizas y en que versión, pues las opciones son muy diferentes.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer version 18.3

Comment: @Lamak Hay clientes que tienen hasta 4 teléfonos y 3 emails por ejemplo. Por eso quiero saber si es posible.

Comment: Es posible, pero necesitarás usar SQL dinámico....y peor aún si esto lo necesitas para más columnas que el teléfono

Comment: porque no agregas todos los numeros en la misma columan y solo separas con una coma? y cuando quieras mostrar haces un split y muestas en una lista los diferentes numeros de mismo nombre

Comment: Dado que cada cliente puede tener mas de un teléfono, para [que cumpla la 1FN](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primera_forma_normal#Ejemplo_2:_Grupos_repetidos_a_través_de_columnas) podrías crearte una tabla de teléfonos por cliente y evitar toda la manipulación de strings en las subsiguientes consultas.